# XmlNodeList xPath to filter out Nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

```
XmlNodeList list = null;
list = xmlResult.SelectNodes("/sitecore
                               /result
                                /item
                                 [scWebsitePath='"+sitecoreContextItemPath+"'
                                  and scTemplateId='"+templateId+"' 
                                  and scDateCreated > '"+publishedFrom+"' 
                                  and scDateCreated < '"+publishedTo+"']");
```

Above code returns me a list of all "validated" Nodes.
Is it also possible to have xPath check wheter a path ie. "xxx/yyy/zzz/" is part of a Node for example if the given path is "xxx/yyy/zzz/" and i want the items below that path to be returned:

- "xxx/yyy/zzz/abc/def/ghi" <- will be
  valid
- "xxx/yyy/zzz/abc/def/ghi/jkl" <- will
  be valid
- "xxx/yyy/zzz/aaa/aaa/zzz" <- won't be
  valid

I can access the node Path by doing this:

```
XmlNode thisScPath = node.SelectSingleNode("scPath");
if (thisScPath == null)
continue;
```

So i wonder if i can also do something like:

```
list = xmlResult.SelectNodes("/sitecore
                               /result
                                /item[scWebsitePath='"+sitecoreContextItemPath+"'
                                      and scTemplateId='"+templateId+"'
                                      and scDateCreated > '"+publishedFrom+"'
                                      and scDateCreated < '"+publishedTo+"'
                                      and scPath = '"+scPath+"/*']");
```

When deleting the invalid Nodes from the list this will save me alot of stress because of bad performance. I can eventually delete the invalid items using a c# string.IndexOf != -1 statement, but I'd like to do this with xPath if possible. Is this possible?

Comment: @Alejandro: Can you, please, explain why is `"xxx/yyy/zzz/aaa/aaa/zzz"` "invalid?" It also starts with `xxx/yyy/zzz/` as the other two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to check

```
  and contains(scPath, 'xxx/yyy/zzz/')
```

or

```
  and starts-with(scPath, 'xxx/yyy/zzz/')
```

in your XPath expression.
If you use the XPath 2.0 implementation from http://www.xqsharp.com/ then you could even use a regular expression and the matches function.

Comment: The search engine retriever that I use is serving results based on System.Xml.XmlDocument. Unfortunatly I can't change the type of the results I get back here. Is it possible to still use the xPath 2.0 implementation you mentioned in you answer and is there also a free implementation of this Xpath 2.0 available?  (I'm developing for commercial use and it costs $200)

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks for editing my question to make it more readable.

Comment: Yes, XQSharp implements extension methods on XmlNode to allow XPath 2.0 http://www.xqsharp.com/xqsharp/doc/1.5/html/Overload_XQSharp_ExtensionMethods_XmlNodeExtensions_XPathSelectNodes.htm. As for an open source XPath 2.0 implementation, Saxon 9 from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ has a .NET version but it does not integrate as nicely with the existing .NET APIs as XQSharp does.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your suggestion on the open source XPath 2.0 implementation!! I will try this out.